# Как повысить точность вычисления чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, decimal

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить следующую проблему: максимальная погрешность при вычислениях 10^(-9), в моем случае погрешность 10^(-8). То есть при входных данных - 3.568248230554, правильный ответ - 10, допустимый ответ 9,999999999, ответ, который получился 9.999999990, то есть мне не хватает точности в один разряд. Как повысить точность **с использованием только встроенных модулей python**?

```
import decimal
from math import pi

d = decimal.Decimal(input("Please enter the d: "))
s = decimal.Decimal(pi) * (d/2) * (d/2)
print(s)
```

Comment: Вычислил вашу формулу на C++, [получил](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/131863fd256ef041) `9.9999999901826211`. Ваше утверждение, что правильный ответ `10` выглядит неправдоподобно.

Comment: Почему правильный ответ 10?

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Скорее всего ответ округлили до 10, что ввело меня в заблуждение. Отдельное спасибо человеку, который проверил на С++, ведь именно такой ответ у меня и получился, однако округленный ответ от заказчика заставил меня думать, что ответ некорректный

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изучите внимательно документацию по модулю [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).  В том его фишка, что вы можете управлять точностью вычислений сами. Для этого есть атрибут  контекста  `getcontext().prec`.

Однако в вашем случае проблtма с точностью самого числа `pi` из модуля `math` или вашим числом 3.568248230554
Давайте проверим вместе.
Вот несколько знаков числа Пи:

```
3,14159 26535 89793 23846 26433  83279 50288 41971 69399 37510
  58209 74944 59230 78164 06286  20899 86280 34825 34211 70679
  82148 08651 32823 06647 09384  46095 50582 23172 53594 08128
  48111 74502 84102 70193 85211  05559 64462 29489 54930 38196
  44288 10975 66593 34461 28475  64823 37867 83165 27120 19091
  45648 56692 34603 48610 45432  66482 13393 60726 02491 41273
  72458 70066 06315 58817 48815  20920 96282 92540 91715 36436
  78925 90360 01133 05305 48820  46652 13841 46951 94151 16094
  33057 27036 57595 91953 09218  61173 81932 61179 31051 18548
  07446 23799 62749 56735 18857  52724 89122 79381 83011 94912
  98336 73362 44065 66430 86021  39494 63952 24737 19070 21798
  60943 70277 05392 17176 29317  67523 84674 81846 76694 05132
  00056 81271 45263 56082 77857  71342 75778 96091 73637 17872
  14684 40901 22495 34301 46549  58537 10507 92279 68925 89235
  42019 95611 21290 21960 86403  44181 59813 62977 47713 09960
  51870 72113 49999 99837 29780  49951 05973 17328 16096 31859
  50244 59455 34690 83026 42522  30825 33446 85035 26193 11881
  71010 00313 78387 52886 58753  32083 81420 61717 76691 47303
  59825 34904 28755 46873 11595  62863 88235 37875 93751 95778
  18577 80532 17122 68066 13001  92787 66111 95909 21642 01989
```

Вот результат decimal:

```
decimal.Decimal(pi)
Out[10]: Decimal('3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875')
```

в то время как настоящее число начинается так:

```
                  3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
```

видно, что совпадает только **3.141592653589793**

```
In [19]: pi = Decimal(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510)

In [20]: pi
Out[20]: Decimal('3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875')

In [21]: pi = Decimal('3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510')

In [22]: pi
Out[22]: Decimal('3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510')
```

Дело в том, что в случае вычисления `Decimal` от `float` максимально возможная точность это точность `float`. А `Decimal` от `str` дает нужное количество цифр.

Но даже правильное pi не дает 10:

```
pi * (d/2) * (d/2)
Out[23]: Decimal('9.999999990182621193277661430')
```

Значит - введенное `d` неверно. Вычислим его.

```
In [32]: dd = Decimal.sqrt(Decimal(10) / pi * 4)

In [33]: dd
Out[33]: Decimal('3.568248232305542229077932745')

In [34]: pi * (dd/2) * (dd/2)
Out[34]: Decimal('9.999999999999999999999999993')
```

В итоге - ваше d тоже вычислялось с точностью флоат.  Более точно оно звучит как '3.568248232305542229077932745'.  Тогда и результат будет поближе к  10.